# Typedef in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to typedef things in javascript somehow? Maybe by getting it from the `prototype` object or something?

For instance, i'd like to typedef the `var` keyword.

```
var string = prototype.var;
```

So now in stead of using 'var' i can use:

```
string blaat = "It's like using the 'var' keyword";
```

Is this possible somehow in javascript?

Comment: Not possible. But suppose it were: what would you stand to gain by "renaming" the `var` keyword?

Comment: `string blaat = 42;` "Oops, my code makes no sense."

Comment: @Jon i had an idea on how to make js code look more like a 'class' based object like you see in Java. But for that i need to typedef some keywords. But appearently this isn't possible.

Comment: @user1175327: Making a language look like something it is definitely not is always a bad idea. Adjust your mindset, not the language.

Comment: Trust me. You do not want to use JavaScript like it was Java. The two are related only *very* superficially. You would limit the language if you did that.

Comment: Just remember javascript is **dynamic** typing **scripting** language with no compiler.

Comment: You could use JSDoc ( http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/ ) to annotate your code. Google Closure Compiler ( https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/ ) and certain IDEs can use that information to do limited type checking.

Comment: typedefing would help minify code for example typedef function fn; could save a lot of bytes in a heavy clients ide app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Period.

Your example is also an impossible thing to want, even though I understand the motivation. JavaScript is dynamically typed. You cannot declare variables to be string. And in that light the whole statement `string x = "foo";` is pointless.

**EDIT** Yes, it's possible to achieve this effect with TypeScript. No, TypeScript is not JavaScript. The question was about the latter. That you can do a similar thing in a completely different programming language does not make this answer incorrect or obsolete.

Declaring a variable as, e.g., `string` will remain impossible in JavaScript until the day when the ECMAScript Standard adds static typing to the language.

Comment: deprecated answer : now you can use Typescript and type any Javascript: http://definitelytyped.org/guides/best-practices.html

Comment: Typescript is a typed superset of Javascript that compiles to plain (dynamically typed) Javascript. I agree with your answer but, according you can mix Javascript and Typecript in the same file, I think it would be a good suggestion for whoever is looking for typing javascript. Doesn't it ?

Comment: On the contrary, it is relevant as it provides a means to work with the semantics the op is seeking.

Comment: @uchuugaka the question is still tagged solely as [tag:javascript]. In that context, this answer is complete and relevant.

Comment: Yes but the comment by @Karbos538 was a suggestion to use a tool that provides "compile" time semantics they are looking for. A good suggestion. Your clarity is still excellent with the Edit too! It's not a completely different language since it is transpiled to JavaScript, at which point the semantics are effectively voided :)

Comment: It is fair to say, until WebAssembly or another tool replace transpilers, that tools that transpile are glorified spellcheckers :)

Comment: I think "foolish" is unnecessarily combative. I upvoted because you're right but I considered downvoting...

Comment: @jcollum You're right, I've smoothed that out a bit.

Comment: I think it's important to note, that JSDoc provides for a @typedef comment to be added that is respected by current IDE's like Webstorm and PHPStorm. This can be done even within a plain JS file to give you pseudo-support for types within the IDE itself.

see: https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html
see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-jsdoc-comments.html#ws_js_jsdoc_typescript_syntax

Answer (score 7):

**You can not override or define keywords in javascript.**

So, No, it can't be done.

Regarding to your example, as @Lightness Races in Orbit [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753105/typedef-in-javascript/9753115#comment12407361_9753105), the example does not make sense as you don't have static typing in javascript(unlike `java`, `C#` etc')!

```
var x = "12";
x = 12;
x = true;
x = function (){/*.../*};
```

All valid!

so let's say you could define `string` to be `var`, will this make sense to you:

```
string x = "12";
x = 12;
x = true;
x = function (){/*.../*};
```

There will be no errors,  but **?!**

Answer (score 2):

This is not a feature of pure JavaScript, but it can be done if you're using Google's Closure Compiler, which allows you to precompile your JavaScript and check the types at compile time.

So you could have

```
/** @type {string} */
var str = "Lorem ipsum";
```

And if `str` were not a string, you'd get a warning when you compile your code.

See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler for more information.